# Integral of the derivative does not work

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In `12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)` writing:

```
Integrate[D[ArcTan[Sqrt[1 + x^5]], x], x]
```

I get:

> ArcTan[Sqrt[1 + x^5]]

but if I write:

```
Integrate[D[ArcTan[x Sqrt[1 + x^5]], x], x]
```

*Mathematica* can no longer solve the integral. Does anything escape me?

Comment: Interesting.  But it can do `D[Integrate[ArcTan[x Sqrt[1 + x^5]], x], x]`.

Comment: `Trace@D[Integrate[ArcTan[x Sqrt[1 + x^5]], x], x]` makes obvious why this way is easier...